# Is it allowed to throw the ball and then catch it again in a table tennis serve?

Tags: rules, table-tennis, serve

Suppose a table tennis player goes to serve. They throw the ball but for whatever reason decide not to play it. Instead they catch it with their hand.

Is this a service fault and therefore a point for the receiver or a let?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw up and catch - Table Tennis Rules

Q:
If I toss the ball up but I don't serve and catch the ball back,  Is it a fault serve?

A:
Yes that is your opponent's point.  As soon as you throw the ball up it is in play. - Alois Rosario

Ref: https://www.pingskills.com/table-tennis-forum/throw-up-and-catch

Comment: In a tournament, yes. But in casual play where you might be interrupted by someone running right behind you as you are tossing the ball to serve, then no.